# CUDA: Instruction fetch issues

Tags: cuda

I have written a kernel which has some issues with instruction fetching. More than 75% of the Issue stall reasons are due to Instruction fetch.

I have no clue of how to improve this. Nvidia does not say anything about the instruction fetch policies and Nsight documentation doesn't bring any light either: "Instruction Fetch stall reason if the next assembly instruction has not yet been fetched."

Is there any way of how I could avoid this issue (or reduce the impact) ?[image]

Comment: What kind of kernel is this? What is your problem case? Can we get to see some code? Could branching be the culprit here?

Comment: So 75% of instruction issue stalls are due instruction fetch, but how many issue stalls are there in the first place? If the warp issue efficiency diagram is correlated, it would seem that instruction issue is stalled for only 6.2% of cycles in the first place, so we are talking about instruction fetch stalls occuring for 4.65% of total cycles, i.e. a minor efficiency issue? One likely cause are branches, in particular backward branches at the end of loops whose body exceeds the size of the instruction cache. If your code contains partially unrolled loops, try to reduce the unroll factor.

Comment: excellent njuffa. You are right, backward branches could be the problem. I don't know if the graphs are correlated but If they are I agree this is a minor issue

Comment: In my simple FMA loop I used aggressive loop unrolling (e.g. 256 loops) but still notice a significant amount of instruction fetch stalls. Actually the percent goes higher with bigger unrolling factors. Can someone explain about this?